# XAML => HTML Equivalent for AutoSize in Grid

Tags: wpf, html, xaml

I'm currently working on a Converter for XAML to HTML! Now I've the Problem that I need to convert a Grid to HTML. I use the css Grid for this. But the problem is, when I have a ColumnWidth of "Auto" in WPF, it's not the same in HTML! In WPF this Column sizes to the with of the Content! How can I do this in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

why not using a HTML table?
autosize would be like:

```
td {
    width: 1px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I tried the HTML Table also, but this does not support the fractions! I'm creating an automatic converter from XAML to HTML, and I need to support all the scenarios

Comment: what do you mean with fractions? can you supply more info and code in the question?

Comment: And how should I Autosize a Row? I've tried "<tr style="height: 1px">! Does not work!